# Let $V$ be finite dimensional vector space. $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ into $V$ and $E$ is a subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, mathematical-physics, matrix-equations

Shows, $T^{-1}(E)={\{u\in V|T(u)\in E}\}$

Prove dim$(T^{-1}(E))$=dim($ker(T)$)+dim($E\cap Im(T)$)

I know eventually I have to prove that dim$(T^{-1}(E))$= dim($ker(T^{-1}(E)$)+dim($Im(T^{-1}(E)$).

but I can't figur out the relationship between them.

Comment: you have a typo, $Im(E)$ does not make sense

Comment: You have a typo (I think): $\dim(Im(E))$ in the last equation. E is a set, so $Im(E)$ is not meaningful

Comment: I edit my question, Is it makes sense now?

Comment: $\mathrm {Ker}(T^{-1}(E))$ does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the restiriction $T|_{T^{-1}E}: T^{-1}(E) \to E$, then the ordinary dimension formula for morphism gives preciswely the desired formula, since $Im(T|_{T^{-1}E})=E \cap Im(T) $

Comment: thanks for replying!  What is the ordinary dimension formula for morphism?

Comment: $\dim(im(f)) + \dim(\ker(f))= \dim(V)$ for $f:V \to W$ vector space homomorphism.

Comment: how is $ker(T^{-1}(E))$ relate to $ker(T)$ ?

Comment: @anqi Luo $\ker(T^{-1}E)$ does not mae sense, since $T^{-1}E$ is not a map, but a vector space. btw, do not forget to prove that $E$ is a v.s.

Answer (score 0):

#### Demo.

**Proof**. $\blacktriangleleft$ First we verify that $\mathcal T^{-1}E$ is a vector space. If $\alpha, \beta \in \mathcal T^{-1}(E)$, then $\mathcal T \alpha + \mathcal T\beta  = \mathcal T (\alpha + \beta) \in E$, thus $\alpha + \beta \in \mathcal T ^{-1}(E)$. Also we could see that $k\alpha \in \mathcal T^{-1 }(E)$ for $\alpha \in \mathcal T^{-1}(E)$ and $k \in \mathbb F$, where $\mathbb F $ is the base field. Note that $E$ is a subspace of $V$, then we have $E \supset \{0\}$. Thus $\mathcal T^{-1} (E) \supset \mathcal T^{-1}(\{0\}) = \mathrm {Ker}\, \mathcal T$. Therefore we could deduce that
$$
\mathrm {Ker}\left(\mathcal T|_{\mathcal T^{-1}(E)} \right) = \mathrm {Ker}\, \mathcal T. 
$$
Now apply the Rank-Nullity theorem to the surjection $\mathcal S:= \mathcal T |_{\mathcal T^{-1}(E)} \colon \mathcal T^{-1}E \to E \cap \mathrm {Im} \, \mathcal T$, then
$$
\dim (\mathcal T^{-1}E) = \dim (\mathrm {Ker}\,\mathcal S) + \dim (\mathrm {Im}\, \mathcal S) = \dim (\mathrm {Ker}\, \mathcal T) + \dim(E \cap \mathrm {Im}\,\mathcal T),
$$
and this is the equation we wanted. $\blacktriangleright$